# Sql Server 2008 Arithmetic Overflow Error Bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been trying to sum the rows of a column using

```
select sum(columnA)
from tableA
```

however I keep getting the error,

`Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint`

`ColumnA` is already set as a bigint in the table and even when i try

```
select sum(cast(columnA as bigint)) from tableA
```

I still get the same error. I know that the sum of the values in the column range should equal somewhere around 111500000000000000. Is this too big for a bigint?

If so how can I get around this error?

Comment: `BIGINT` range is as follows `-2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)` size is 8 Bytes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

Comment: Are you sure that is the range for the sum of that column?  The value is within the limit of a `bigint`.  What if you try casting to a `numeric(38, 0)` data type?

Comment: I've just run a query with the same approximate syntax [select cast sum(x) as bigint from table y] on my SQL server.  It ran, albeit being much smaller.  Is it possible there's some non-numeric data in the table?  What is the datatype of the column as-is?

Comment: The datatype of the column is bigint. There is no non-numeric data in the column

Comment: I also go this to run: cast(sum(9999999999999999999) as bigint) - put the SUM inside the CAST

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that total `SUM` might be to large for `BIGINT` you can always split it into 2 queries, if you have primary key or some other way to divide the data. This would be great test to figure out what total sum actually is.

```
 SELECT SUM(columnA)
 FROM tableA
 Where PrimaryID < 50 --Or what ever is half your data

 SELECT SUM(columnA)
 FROM tableA
 Where PrimaryID >= 50
```

After you get individual `SUM` you can verify the total, if it still does not work you can always break into more queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. `decimal(38,0)` is the biggest number data type that SQL Server can handle (holds larger numbers than `bigint`).

```
select sum(cast(columnA as decimal(38,0))) from tableA
```